# Bad shading on a low-poly face model

Tags: modeling, shaders, topology

I have a slight shading issue as shown in the image below.

[image]

I tried to fix this with *Shade Smooth*, recalculating normals, etc, but to no avail. The problem persists when I view the model in *3ds Max*.

[image]

Applying a *Subdivision* modifier in Blender or a *TurboSmooth* modifier in *3ds Max* does help mitigate the problem, but it's still visible to the naked eye.

[image]

The mesh looks fine when I check it with *X View* in *3ds Max*.

[image]

The issue becomes more apparent when baking a *Normal Map* as shown here:

[image]

Here is the *Normal Map* when baked in *ZBrush*

[image]

Unfortunately, the weird shading issue still shows up in a specular view.

[image]

It gets worse though when applying the baked normal map.

[image]

So my question is what causes this weird low poly issue, is there any way I can fix this, or is subdivision the only solution? And why does it affect the baking of a normal map? How to bake the perfect normal map? I tried baking normal maps in *Marmoset* and *3ds Max*, but the issue persists in Blender.

---

Thanks a lot, Yousuf. I have tried your solution but unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case.

[image]

I did try *Auto Smooth* of up to 180 before

[image]

Here's the file:
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the object?

Comment: You could try auto smooth.

Comment: thanks Duarte. And  how delete the wrong answer I post myself .  Its my first time here

Comment: how to share my object,? moonboots

Comment: share ur blend file at https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: thanks  u Harry.  I have up load  the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the smoothing, go to the *Object Data Properties* tab and enable *Auto Smooth*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like normal behaviour, your current topology is at the end of the day a low poly representation of what should be curved surfaces. Without the appropriate mesh density, the result is that you are not describing a smooth curve, but instead sharp edges. Smoothing the normals will just help hide the edges themselves, but if your faces are at a square angle, it's still a far stretch that smooth shading can't hide. You wouldn't expect smooth shading to make a cube look good? Well, it's the same here:

[image]

Furthermore, you have many quadrilaterals that have their diagonal vertices on a different plane, like this one:

[image]

And at the end of the day, you did shape your brow bone quite sharp, to begin with:

[image]

If that isn't your intention, maybe smooth the shape a little more. A quick sculpt pass with the smooth brush, and it will be gone.

All that said, this is expected from a low poly mesh. And the best way to fix that without compromising the low poly budgets is simply to bake a normal map from a higher resolution mesh that correctly describes the smooth curves of that area.

Just to give an idea of the difference, here's the result of your model with a normal map baked from a copy of that model with subdivision modifier level 2:

[image]